# Original proof of Hilbert irreducibility theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Does there exist a modern exposition of Hilbert's original (1892) proof of the Hilbert irreducibility theorem? Of course, I can (and will) read Hilbert's original article, but I would feel more confident if I can compare my understanding of what goes on with someone else's.

I mean the following article by Hilbert:

Hilbert, David.
[Ueber die Irreducibilität ganzer rationaler Functionen mit ganzzahligen Coefficienten](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1892.110.104).
J. Reine Angew. Math. 110 (1892), 104–129.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Hilbert's Proof of His Irreducibility Theorem](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2018.1448181) by Mark B. Villarino, Bill Gasarch, and Kenneth Regan. (Also available as an [arXiv preprint](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1611.06303).)

Comment: Thanks Peter! It is exactly what I was looking for!